# Arabic(hijri) calendar/datepicker using smartclient

Tags: calendar, arabic, smartclient, hijri

I am working on an arabic language support project using smartclient 10.0. 
It requires an arabic(hijri) calendar support for date picker component.

How can I add arabic(hijri) calendar for date picker component in smartclient?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to define month names in arabic, and maybe the picker grid to be ordered in another way. Then you will need to extend the DateItem for DynamicForm. Check here: http://www.smartclient.com/docs/10.0/a/b/c/go.html#class..Class
http://www.smartclient.com/docs/10.0/a/b/c/go.html#object..ClassFactory

If that is not the case, and you just need to define the order of days, months, years according to arabic specifics, please check here:
http://www.smartclient.com/docs/10.0/a/b/c/go.html#type..DateInputFormat
http://www.smartclient.com/docs/10.0/a/b/c/go.html#type..DateDisplayFormat

Also take a look here:
http://www.smartclient.com/docs/10.0/a/b/c/go.html#group..i18n

Hope this helps.